# Notification message does not show in started activity

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

When I receive a notification and click on the tab in the drag-down from bar, a message activity is starting but does not show the received message.

The next messages are showing well while the message activity is active.

How can I display the first / opening message as well?

Thanks.

GCMIntentService.java (part)

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MessageActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }
```

MessageActivity.class

```
public class MessageActivity extends Activity {
    // label to display gcm messages
    TextView lblMessage;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MessageActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "U heeft geen verbinding met internet!", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    }       

    /**
     * Receiving push messages
     * */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());
            // Showing received message
            lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nieuw bericht: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I solved it this way:

Added in GCMIntentService.java

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

and in MessageActivity.class

```
TextView message= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);
message.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("message"));
```

Comment: Harry, you saved me 3 hours of searching why notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message); is not sent. This is mandatory: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Your `BroadcastReceiver` is only registered when the `MessageActivity` is running.  You need to register it in the manifest so that it will work when the `MessageActivity`is not running.

IIRC you will need to extend `BroadcastReceiver` to be able to do this.

Comment: Sorry I did not mentioned that: MessageActivity is registered in the Manifest

Comment: You need to register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest as well. Also how are you starting `GCMIntentService`?

Comment: In the manifest: <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" /> and also: <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"

Comment: So the `GCMBroadcastReceiver` starts the `GCMIntentService` which displays a `Notification`.  You open the `Notification` which starts the `Activity` but doesn't show the `Toast`.  Only subsequent messages show a `Toast`?